# What type of tree is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

I photographed this group of trees a couple of years ago at the northern tip of [Prudence Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prudence_Island) in Narragansett Bay. Any idea what species these are?

[image: Trees on Prudence Island]

[image: Tree closeup]

Comment: Do you have any better pictures (i.e., close-ups of leaves or bark)? Also, what would you estimate their height to be? Any interesting characteristics to note? Did you see any seeds or flowers?

Comment: @theforestecologist These are the best photos I have, I'm afraid.  Height maybe 15-20 feet.  I was hoping someone could identify at least down to the family based on the location and overall growth form.

Comment: I'll try to give it a closer look then. Orient me real quick - are those flowers or young leaves  at the end of the branches? Is oppositely arranged, which should reduce our options

Comment: @theforestecologist Those are young leaves.  The photos were taken in May 2014.

Answer (score 2):

Although it can't be said definitively because of the picture quality, these are actually very likely maple trees. It's possible that they are either **Red Maple** (***Acer rubrum***) or **sycamore maple** (**Acer pseudoplatanus**) trees in spring leafout.

[image]

<sup>[Source](http://plants.homesteadgardens.com/Content/Images/Photos/H032-25.jpg)</sup>

Evidence:

- The branches have an [opposite arrangement](http://lib.du.ac.ir/documents/10157/60743/Plant+Identification+Terminology+Glossary.pdf). Very few tree are opposite (see [MADHORSE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/41398/16866))
- The Rhode Island Wild Plant Society [claims](http://riwps.org/prudence-islands-south-end/) that red maple is abundant on the northern part of the island.
- The Virginia Cooperative Extension provides an incomplete but detailed [list of trees that can tolerate salt spray](http://pubs.ext.vt.edu/content/dam/pubs_ext_vt_edu/430/430-031/430-031_pdf.pdf).

  - Two maples, *Acer psudoplatanus* and *Acer campestre*, (which are tolerant of salt spray) are both present as an exotic plant in that region of the country (see BONAP range map [1](http://bonap.net/MapGallery/County/Acer%20pseudoplatanus.png) and [2](http://bonap.net/MapGallery/County/Acer%20campestre.png))
  - The [Prudence Island flora](http://nbnerr.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ecol-Profile-CH05-Flora.pdf) mentions that *A. pseudoplatanus* is a common escaped cultivar on the island.
- I'm leaning toward Red maple because of the red leaves appearing -- this is more typical of *A. rubrum* compared to the often more yellowish spring leaves of *A. pseudoplatanus*.

Note: The salt spray and windy environment will cause these trees (and most vegetation along a coastline) to develop "strange" (often gnarly) tree shapes.